# convert Spark dataframe to scala dictionary like format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which i need to convert to `(key, value)` pairs. below is the format:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|                 cid|                 uid|               date|rating|  type|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|          1111111111|           user1-316|2019-10-11 14:01:49|     1|others|
|          1111111111|               user1|2019-10-11 14:25:35|     2|mobile|
|          1111111111|               user2|2019-10-11 14:30:05|     3|others|
|          1111111112|               user2|2019-10-11 14:16:58|     4|others|
|          1111111113|               user2|2019-10-11 14:32:00|     1|mobile|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+------+
```

i need ta aggregate it based on `uid` and create a list of `cid`,`rating`,`date` for each `type`

```
 uid       | history
-----------+--------------------------------------------------------
 user1-316 | {"others": [["1111111111", 1, "2019-10-11 14:01:49"]]}
 user1     | {"mobile": [["1111111111", 2, "2019-10-11 14:25:35"]]}
 user2     | {"others": [["1111111111", 3, "2019-10-11 14:30:05"],["1111111112", 4, "2019-10-11 14:16:58"]],"mobile":[["1111111113", 1, "2019-10-11 14:32:00"]]}
```

In python i can achive this as we have `dict` format. How do we get this done in scala.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

You can try something like this. I am not sure dict in Python but for (key,value), Scala has `map` type.

```
scala> df.show
+----------+---------+-------------------+------+------+
|       cid|      uid|               date|rating|  type|
+----------+---------+-------------------+------+------+
|1111111111|user1-316|2019-10-11 14:01:49|     1|others|
|1111111111|    user1|2019-10-11 14:25:35|     2|mobile|
|1111111111|    user2|2019-10-11 14:30:05|     3|others|
|1111111112|    user2|2019-10-11 14:16:58|     4|others|
|1111111113|    user2|2019-10-11 14:32:00|     1|mobile|
+----------+---------+-------------------+------+------+

scala> df.withColumn("col1",array("cid","rating","date"))
         .groupBy("type","uid")
         .agg(map(col("type"),collect_list("col1")).as("col2")) 
         .groupBy("uid")
         .agg(collect_list(col("col2")).as("history"))
         .show(false)

+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|uid      |history                                                                                                                                       |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|user1-316|[[others -> [[1111111111, 1, 2019-10-11 14:01:49]]]]                                                                                          |
|user1    |[[mobile -> [[1111111111, 2, 2019-10-11 14:25:35]]]]                                                                                          |
|user2    |[[others -> [[1111111111, 3, 2019-10-11 14:30:05], [1111111112, 4, 2019-10-11 14:16:58]]], [mobile -> [[1111111113, 1, 2019-10-11 14:32:00]]]]|
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: my bad....didn't see the question properly. I have updated my answer but your last question is still unresolved ( having `others` and `mobile` outside the list as a dictionary/map).

Answer (score 0):

AS said, we can have Key -> Value pair in scala, but not with the similar representation of Python

First, read the data

```
scala> val df = Seq((1111111111,"user1-316","2019-10-1114:01:49",1,"others"), (1111111111,"user1","2019-10-1114:25:35",2,"mobile"), (1111111111,"user2","2019-10-1114:30:05",3,"others"), (1111111112,"user2","2019-10-1114:16:58",4,"others"), (1111111113,"user2","2019-10-1114:32:00",1,"mobile")).toDF("cid","uid","date","rating","type")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cid: int, uid: string ... 3 more fields]
scala> df.show
+----------+---------+------------------+------+------+
|       cid|      uid|              date|rating|  type|
+----------+---------+------------------+------+------+
|1111111111|user1-316|2019-10-1114:01:49|     1|others|
|1111111111|    user1|2019-10-1114:25:35|     2|mobile|
|1111111111|    user2|2019-10-1114:30:05|     3|others|
|1111111112|    user2|2019-10-1114:16:58|     4|others|
|1111111113|    user2|2019-10-1114:32:00|     1|mobile|
+----------+---------+------------------+------+------+
```

Now, we convert cid,rating,date to list

```
scala> val df1 = df.groupBy($"uid", $"type").agg(collect_list(array($"cid", $"rating", $"date")).as("aggNew"))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [uid: string, type: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df1.show(false)
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|uid      |type  |aggNew                                                                                            |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|user1    |mobile|[WrappedArray(1111111111, 2, 2019-10-1114:25:35)]                                                 |
|user2    |mobile|[WrappedArray(1111111113, 1, 2019-10-1114:32:00)]                                                 |
|user1-316|others|[WrappedArray(1111111111, 1, 2019-10-1114:01:49)]                                                 |
|user2    |others|[WrappedArray(1111111111, 3, 2019-10-1114:30:05), WrappedArray(1111111112, 4, 2019-10-1114:16:58)]|
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

On top of it, applying groupBy on uid for obtaining required `(key, values)`

```
scala> df1.groupBy($"uid").agg(collect_list(map($"type", $"aggNew"))).show(false)
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|uid      |collect_list(map(type, aggNew))                                                                                                                                                                              |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|user1-316|[Map(others -> WrappedArray(WrappedArray(1111111111, 1, 2019-10-1114:01:49)))]                                                                                                                               |
|user1    |[Map(mobile -> WrappedArray(WrappedArray(1111111111, 2, 2019-10-1114:25:35)))]                                                                                                                               |
|user2    |[Map(mobile -> WrappedArray(WrappedArray(1111111113, 1, 2019-10-1114:32:00))), Map(others -> WrappedArray(WrappedArray(1111111111, 3, 2019-10-1114:30:05), WrappedArray(1111111112, 4, 2019-10-1114:16:58)))]|
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Added schema

```
root
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_list(map(type, aggNew)): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: this gives us a list of list, but need `mobile` and `others` not inside `list` but inside `dict` is that possible

Comment: Added schema to support my point. Dict is python's key-value pairs collection object, while Map is Scala's Key-value pair collection object. Only difference is names & representation. You can see "map" keyword in the last operation(I accept it is weird to use collect_list every time, but spark needs that to execute. Tried without it but it is throwing error. We can use "map" individually without groupBy, but in your case, groupBy is must and key value pairs should be in a list, it is just Spark way). But I am sure my result is not list of lists :)